# How to start audio in a browser in iPhone without user confirmation?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I wrote a script in PHP that beeps if there is space in the course i want to register. The problem is I gotta keep my PC open for it to work and i can't carry it with me 24/7.

Now if I open that page on my iphone it does not beep because Apple do not allow automatic sound starts without user confirmation. There is no workaround I could find.

I was wondering if there are any workarounds or alternative ways? How can I make the "beep" work in iphone?

iOS versions: 6.1 and 7.0

Comment: Couldn't you just have your PHP script auto-register you for the course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't able to find a work around because, as far as I know, Apple doesn't allow you to bypass this. It's an intentional design decision by them, and one that many people would agree is a good practice. In your circumstance, I can see how this is undesirable.